# Add offset to a last row

Tags: excel, vba

I just want to add an `offset (0,6)` to my `lastRow` . any help?

```
lastRow = oSht.Range(vari1 & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: What you mean offset to last row? or you mean to `vari1`?

Answer (score 1):

After your clarification I could suggest that you could do it by range expansion. Instead of `Offset` you could use `Resize`.

As you said this is working correct for your `S column`:

```
oSht.Range(vari2, vari1 & lastRow).Select
```

After we add resize to that you get your new range:

```
oSht.Range(vari2, vari1 & lastRow).Resize(,6).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim vari1 As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant column letter
    vari1 = "S"

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With oSht
        lastRow = .Range(vari1 & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set Rng = .Range(vari1 & 2 & ":" & .Range(vari1 & lastRow).Offset(, 6).Address)

        '~~> S2:X32 in your case if lastrow is 32
        Debug.Print Rng.Address
    End With
End Sub
```